# Why below code gives segmentation fault problem?

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to find the minimun number in an array using recursive function.but my code gives segemtation fault .

```
main()
{
    int a[5]={2,1,4,5,3};
    int n=1;
    fumi(a,n,a[0],5);
}

fumi(int a[],int n,int min,int t)
{
    if(n==t)
    {
        printf("%d",min);
    }
    if(a[n]<min)
    {
        min=a[n];
    }
    return(fumi(a,n+1,min,t));
}
```

Where am doing wrong and also main is not returning anything is not reason for segmentation fault.

Comment: Note : as an exercise for recursion, this may be interesting, but in a real program, this is an _extremely_ bad idea.

Comment: When you want to sort `a[10000]` (not sure of the number), you are going to have your program crashing (by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow ), unless the compiler remove the recursion as an optimization. While the non recursive function takes 5 lines, takes way less memory, is easier to understand, and (also) is faster.

Comment: @Amit Singh Tomar C compilers are not required to apply the tail call optimization. If a compiler does not apply it, your program will run out of stack (and terminate abruptly) for moderately sized arrays.

Comment: Agreed, this is a terrible candidate for a recursive solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should also `return` after `printf("%d",min);` otherwise, you check `if (a[t] < min)`, and `a[t]` was not allocated.

```
fumi(int a[],int n,int min,int t)
{
    if(n==t)
    {
        printf("%d",min);
        return; //This line was added
    }
    if(a[n]<min)
    {
        min=a[n];
    }
    return(fumi(a,n+1,min,t));
}
```

Comment: @Amit Singh Tomar: you didn't stop the recursion, and when trying to access a[5], which was not allocated by you, you got a seg-fault. the return, after printing stopped the recursion and prevented accessing not allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very close to working.  The reason it crashes is because the recursion never stops and goes on part the end of the array.

You correctly check for `n == t` and print out the result, but after that you don't return.  The code keeps running on to infinity.  Simply adding a return after the `printf` solves the problem:

```
void fumi(int a[],int n,int min,int t)
{
    if(n==t)
    {
        printf("%d",min);
        return; // stop recursing
    }
    if(a[n]<min)
    {
        min=a[n];
    }
    fumi(a,n+1,min,t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After executing

```
if(n==t)
{
    printf("%d",min);
}
```

It does not return, instead it goes on doing:

```
if(a[n]<min)
{
    min=a[n];
}
```

So when the base condition satisfies it does not return. Therefore the `fumi` function is always called recursively.

Two causes of segfault:

1. As `n` goes beyond the max array length, an unallocated (illegal) memory access triggers it
2. As the recursion does not return, we get a stack overflow, leads to a segmentation fault.

whichever occurs first.

Therefore the correction your code needs is to return when it encounters the base condition:

```
if(n==t)
{
    printf("%d",min);
    return;
}
```